# Can I initialize 2D array starting with 1 in for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a 2D array in Java, I want the array to look something like below:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    int[][] board = new int[3][3]; 
    System.out.println(board.length);
    for (int i = 1; i <= board.length; i++) { 
        for (int j = 1; j <= board[i].length; j++) { 
            board[i][j] = 1; 
            System.out.println(board[i][j]);
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

This is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

When I try with `i = 0` and `j = 0` in the `for` loop. It works fine.

Comment: index of an array of length `len` are from `0` to `len - 1`. And array of size `2` has elements at index `0` and `1`

Comment: What is the reason for starting i and j with 1?

Comment: I will be needing it to solve chess board problem

Answer (score 0):

you are looping until `<= board.length` and `<= board[i].length`.

This should in fact only be `< board.length` and `< board[i].length`, since an array index ranges from `0-array.length - 1`. You should therefore also start with `i = 0` and `j = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the termination condition of your `for` loop. You are using `i <= board.length` when you should be using `i < board.length`. The same goes for the second loop with `j <= board[i].length`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) { 
        board[i][j] = 1; 
        System.out.println(board[i][j]);
    } 
}
```

Rember that in Java, the first index of an array is at index 0, so the last index is at index `length - 1`.

Comment: If I do  not use `i <= board.length`, only few of the array indexes is filled with value.

Comment: @Archana Then you should also start with `i = 0` and `j = 0`, which i didn´t see directly either.